# Is it possible to write vertex array code that's portable between OpenGL 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: opengl, vao, opengl-2.0

The [OpenGL 3.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec30.pdf) says:

> **E.1 Profiles and Deprecated Features of OpenGL 3.0**
>
> ...
>
> Client vertex arrays - all vertex array attribute pointers must refer
> to buffer objects (section 2.9.2). The default vertex array object
> (the name zero) is also deprecated. Calling **VertexAttribPointer** when
> no buffer object or no vertex array object is bound will generate an
> `INVALID_OPERATION` error, as will calling any array drawing command
> when no vertex array object is bound.

The [ref page for **glEnableVertexAttribArray**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml) says:

> `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated by **glEnableVertexAttribArray** and **glDisableVertexAttribArray** if no vertex array object is bound.

The message I'm hearing is that comprehensive vertex array code that's fully portable between OpenGL 2.x and OpenGL 3.x/3.2+ is impossible, since 2.x can't use VAOs (which the API surface can strictly enforce -- thanks GLAD!), and 3.x must use VAOs (which...some drivers *maaaybe* enforce?)

It seems to me that robust code must branch between dedicated 2.x and 3.x codepaths (detected at runtime) at some point. Is this true?

Comment: (I...am aware that this may be a time capsule of a question better suited for 2010 than 2020, but 2.x is of some importance to me here haha.)

Comment: You *can* just create & bind a VAO at startup & then forget it exists and proceed as if you were using a GL 2.x context, at least as far as vertex setup/submission goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context), then you can run the code of all previous OpenGL versions. Vertex array object 0 is valid and you can use fixed function attributes, immediate mode (`glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences) or even mix them all together.
Compare [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)  and [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf).

The specification of all OpenGL versions can be found at [Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php).

Comment: Ahhhhh, I completely misunderstood what the Compatability Profile entailed. I thought it was just to check that deprecated functionality was available, not provide different implementations of APIs. Thank you!